# How to SELECT using both wildcards (LIKE) and array (IN)?

Tags: sql, sql-like

In SQL, if you want to perform a SELECT with a wildcard, you'd use:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE field_name LIKE '%value%'
```

If you wanted to use an array of possible values, you'd use:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE field_name IN ('one', 'two', 'three')
```

But, what would you do if you wanted to use both wildcards AND an array?

Kind of like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE field_name LIKE IN ('%one', '_two', 'three[abv]')
```

Comment: If you're using MySQL, this is a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using SQL LIKE and IN together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318126/using-sql-like-and-in-together)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE field_name LIKE '%one'
   OR field_name LIKE '_two'
   OR field_name LIKE 'three[abv]'
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the overhead of this, but it would seem to be the only way. As it happens, even doing it this way causes a massive overhead as I have an array of a couple of hundred entries. Using just IN is fast. LIKE takes forever :/

Answer (score 5):

you can use join with like statement like below query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name t 
JOIN dbo.Split('one,two,three',',') s ON t.field_name LIKE N'%'+s.item+'%'
```

I create this function to split string:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (@StringToSplit NVARCHAR(MAX), @SpliterChar CHAR(1))
RETURNS
    @returnList TABLE ([item] [NVARCHAR] (500))
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @nItem NVARCHAR(500);
 DECLARE @pos INT; 
 WHILE CHARINDEX(@SpliterChar, @StringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(@SpliterChar, @StringToSplit); 
  SELECT @nItem = SUBSTRING(@StringToSplit, 1, @pos-1);
  if (@nItem <> '') INSERT INTO @returnList SELECT @nItem;
  SELECT @StringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@StringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@StringToSplit)-@pos);
 END
 if (@StringToSplit<>'') INSERT INTO @returnList SELECT @StringToSplit;
 RETURN
END
```

Comment: Nice one-liner. Nowadays this system function can be used: STRING_SPLIT ( string , separator [ , enable_ordinal ] ), so request will look like:

    SELECT * FROM table_name t JOIN STRING_SPLIT('one,two,three',',') s ON t.field_name LIKE N'%'+s.value+'%'