# SELECT from table Where Column includes Either

Tags: php, android, mysql

Please help me am a beginner:

I want to select data from sql column let's say image_description which contains data in form of tags. e.g one entry in the column is "Moscow, lights, water, Russia, night". The other table entries in this column contain data in a similar format.

I want to use keywords to select the data and put them in a constant say $tag. So the $tag variable may contain at one point  e'g "Moscow, lights, water, Russia, night" from above.

How can I formulate my SELECT statement to fetch any row which includes any word in my $tag variable.

Comment: a simple select query can result in proper data......select * from table_name where column_name like '%your_string%';

Comment: As juergen said, [normalize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246701/what-is-normalisation-or-normalization) your tabels. I highly recommend creating another table where you can store single tags belonging to a image. The table would include `image_id` and `tag`.
When an image has multiple tags, there would be multiple entries in this table, one for each tag.

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea to use mulitple values in single column if matching with whole tag..
but if you are using the same way, try something like this

```
$string1= yoursting_var.",";
$string2= ", ".yoursting_var.",";
$string3=", ".yourstring_var;
select * from table_name where (column_name like '$string1%' || column_name like '%$string2%' || column_name like '%$string3');..
```

if you use simple like %string%, it will create problem in comparing some words which comes in other words as well. like "water" and "ate", if you search with "ate" it will return both.

//for mulitple words

```
$words_arr;  // this is your words array contain any nummber of words

$com_string="";

foreach($words_arr as $words){
    $string1= $words.",";

    $string2= ", ".$words.",";

    $string3=", ".$words;

//make query using loop for all words with AND/OR  condition    
    $com_string .= " AND (column_name like '$string1%' || column_name like '%$string2%' ||column_name like '%$string3')";

}

select * from table_name where 1 $com_string;
```

Comment: Thank you Tariq..What if I don't know the number of words in the variable. Like the way you used 3 words in your example. It is generated by a system so number of words may vary..sometimes "word1,word2,word3" or sometimes "word 1, word 3" or even "word 1, word3, word7, word 4" etc

Comment: it will be easier if u change your table structure.. but in this case you need some trick

$words_arr;  // this is your words array contain any nummber of words

$com_string="";

foreach($words_arr as $words){
    $string1= $words.",";

    $string2= ", ".$words.",";

    $string3=", ".$words;

//make query using loop for all words with AND/OR  condition    
    $com_string .= " AND (column_name like '$string1%' || column_name like '%$string2%' ||column_name like '%$string3')";
    
}

select * from table_name where 1 $com_string;

Comment: @KaiLean just append them to your query string; something along the lines of ```queryString = 'SELECT * from blabla... WHERE condition1; queryString+='OR condition2;';```

Comment: check answer for multiple word hv just edited.. might this will help you

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

`SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE image_description LIKE 'your_tag%';`

Or if you want to check for multiple tags, just add `OR` conditions, like this:
`SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE image_description LIKE 'your_tag%'
  OR image_description LIKE 'your_second_tag%
  OR image_description LIKE 'your_third_tag%;`

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520469/sql-how-to-select-using-both-wildcards-like-and-array-in) question out;

Comment: Works only when the variable contains only one word

Comment: @KaiLean Edited. Just use a ```for``` statement to append ```OR``` conditions to your queryString