# using % (as LIKE) in IN

Tags: mysql, concatenation, sql-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using SQL LIKE and IN together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318126/using-sql-like-and-in-together)

I have table as below.

```
create table tab1 (
    id int, col1 varchar(20), col2 varchar(20),
    col3 varchar(20), col4 varchar(20)
);
```

I have values inside it as

```
insert into tab1 values
(1,'column011','column012','column013','column014'),
(2,'column021','column022','column023','column024'),
(3,'column031','column032','column033','column034'),
(4,'column041','column042','column043','column044')
;
```

Earlier I had requirement as, **Find row, where any column HAVE data as `column011`**. So I executed below query and got what I was desired.

```
select * from tab1
WHERE 'column011' in (col1,col2,col3,col4);
```

I have used above against `CONCAT_WS` as it was simple query.

```
select * from tab1 
where CONCAT_WS('-', col1, col2, col3, col4) LIKE '%column011%';
```

Now I got requirement as, **Find row, where any column CONTAIN data as `mn01`**. So I executed below query and got what I was desired.

```
select * from tab1 
where CONCAT_WS('-', col1, col2, col3, col4) LIKE '%mn01%';
```

However I was thinking to get this done by using simple query (first query). So I tried with below.

```
select * from tab1
WHERE '%mn01%' in (col1,col2,col3,col4);
```

Is there any way where I can do what I want by modifying above query? (Last query)

### [Data at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6018/7)

Comment: Possibly because there are a hundreds of duplicates on this exact question covering every major RDBMS?

Comment: @Ben : The link you provided doesn't looks DUPLICATE to me. Can you provide me few more duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

How about a variable?

```
set @var = 'mn01';
select * from tab1
WHERE '%' & @var & '%' in (col1,col2,col3,col4);
```

Comment: it is giving me all rows

Comment: @FahimParkar please share if you see any duplicate entries to your question. I am eager to explore.

Comment: Ok. regarding all entries, [this is what I was talking about](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6018/10)