# is it possible to use % operator in the NOT IN() to look for word parts instead of exact phrases?

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL, is there a way to use something similar to the "LIKE '%closed%' but used in  the "NOT IN()" function?

I have data in a table that allows the end user to specify their own "closed" status for a work order.  Some of the users write their own status as follows:

```
Closed
Pending Approval
1-Open
3-Closed
2-In progress
Pending
```

As you can see, I have a status called "3-Closed".  I am trying to gather all the records that are NOT considered "closed", but this "3-Closed" will not work with my "NOT IN()" sql below.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE
    p_wo_status_cat_id IN 
             (
              SELECT b1.p_wo_status_cat_id 
              FROM p_status_list b1 
              WHERE LOWER(b1.name) NOT IN('completed','finished','done','closed')

              )
```

Is there a way to do some thing like this:

```
NOT IN ('%closed%')
```

so it would pick up any variances of the word "closed"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using SQL LIKE and IN together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318126/using-sql-like-and-in-together)

Comment: Not an very good idea to use an WHERE ... IN ( SELECT .... syntax this will force an full table scan on the table my_table.. if p_wo_status_cat_id is an primary key or unique key you should really rewrite this to an INNER JOIN this will than run better on large tables

Comment: What are `completed`, `finished` and `done`? Are they user statuses? If you are listing them explicitly, why don't you want to list the `3-Closed` status explicitly as well?

Comment: good point Raymond...i've rewritten it to join on the table on the primary key you suggested.  Thanks.

Comment: I dont know if this would help [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c809ff/2/0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not with the same syntax as `IN`, but [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) can do this. For a single comparison:

```
NOT REGEXP 'closed'
```

For multiple comparisons (i.e. match anything that does not contain either "foo" or "bar":

```
NOT REGEXP '(foo|bar)'
```

Comment: Perfect!  This worked like a charm and accomplished exactly what I needed it to!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that.  The IN funciton takes exact matches.

You can use NOT LIKE.

A better way to write the query would potentially be to restructure your data.  Add a column that says is_closed or is_closing_statment that is a bit.  Then a 1 means that this word closes the issue and you can rewrite your query to only get the staments that close the issues.  Using your sample data:

```
Closed                 1
Pending Approval       0
1-Open                 0
3-Closed               1
2-In progress          0
Pending                0
```

Then you filter to states that close and limit your results to issues that have that state.