# Selecting rows with more than 1 LIKE

Tags: mysql, search, sql-like

My problem here is that, I want to create a simple search engine.
I've got it to work by using 2 queries. The first one searches for the full search term and the second one searches for all of the matches word by word.
For example if You search for `"The long lasting i don't know"`, then it will search for `"The long lasting i don't know"`, then for `"The"`, then `"long"`, and so on.

But I want to use pagination and It would mess up the results, so I need it in 1 query.
Is it achieveable with the `IN` operator?

Comment: Are you using a full text index on the column?

Comment: Maybe I didn`t get exacly what you want, but I think that is something like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172195/mysql-like-multiple-values ?

Comment: @Rowland Shaw No, should I use it?

Comment: @KioCoan Yes, something like that. But can I use the in operator like this:
IN (%somequery1%, %somequery2%, %somequery3%, %somequery4% ...)?

Comment: I would strongly recommend using a full text index on the column, and using the [full text search functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) over trying to reimplement yourself in client code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using REGEXP as said by @jazkat at [Mysql Like multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172195/mysql-like-multiple-values)

Your query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP "The long lasting i don't know|The|long|lasting|i|don't|know"
```

More about REGEXP here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-regexps.htm

Comment: This solution seems the most efficient way to solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use individual like with ORs as follows

```
select * from tablename where field like "%The long lasting i don't know%" or field like "%The%" or field like "%long%" or field like "%lasting%" or field like "%i%" or field like "%don't%" or field like "%know%"
```

refer this link [Using SQL LIKE and IN together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318126/using-sql-like-and-in-together)

Answer (score 1):

My answer may not be optimal on the performance side, but here's the idea I got.

You could search only with the word by word (column like '%The%' or column like '%long% etc.).  You would surely get the results containing the whole sentence.

Then, you can order it with a case

```
Order By Case When Column Like "The long lasting i don't know%" Then 1 Other 2 End
```