# How to write query like WHERE ban IN ('apple', 'banana', 'coconut') where ban will match banana

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to search inside comma separated string . I know its possible by using IN operator but its return only if its match 100%. I want like 
WHERE ban IN ('apple', 'banana', 'coconut','bangladesh') where ban will match banana ,bangladesh . 
Sorry for my bad English and advanced thanks for all .

Comment: Hint: `Like %..%`

Comment: You can use multiple LIKE with OR clause [refer this link ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318126/using-sql-like-and-in-together)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using SQL LIKE and IN together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318126/using-sql-like-and-in-together)

Comment: You can use multiple LIKE with OR clause [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318126/using-sql-like-and-in-together)

Comment: Thanks all of you . If use reverse it like Where bangladesh IN ('Ban','Bana') is it possible by anyhow ?

Comment: Please provide some examples of what you want to succeed _and_ some that should fail.  (It may be easier to show examples than to struggle with English.)