# How to use sql IN clause with sql LIKE

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I have spring boot application , in that in one of DAO class , we have one method where we are retrieving some data , for that we are using below query , here am using `namedParameterJdbcTemplate`

```
select student_id from student_records where create_date >= timestamp '"+appProps.getFromDate()+"' and  create_date <= timestamp '"+appProps.getToDate()+"' and student_id in (:studentIdList)
```

the complete method is like below

```
public List<String> readMatchingStudentIds_ALL(List<String> inputStudentIdsList){
            List<String> macthingStudentIdsList = new ArrayList<>();
            try{
                Map<String, List<String>> namedParameters = Collections.singletonMap("studentIdsList", inputStudentIdsList);
                String query = " select student_id from student_records where create_date >= timestamp '"+appProps.getFromDate()+"' and  create_date <= timestamp '"+appProps.getToDate()+"' and student_id in (:studentIdList)";

                macthingStudentIdsList =  namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, namedParameters, String.class);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(),e);
            }
            return macthingStudentIdsList;
     }
```

everything working fine , but now problems coming , for example the incoming student is list contains "AFE1245" but in our db we have data like below "000AEF1245" , what i means 0's are prefixed , we do not know how many 0's are prefixed , for single query we can use LIKE operator like below

```
select student_id from student_records where student_id like '%input_student_id'
```

but my case is different as we need to use sql `IN` clause , is their any possibility we can use sql `IN` clause and `LIKE` both or is their any other way

Comment: `col1 IN(1,2,3 )` is just an abbreviated form of  `( col1=1 or col1=2 or col1=3 )` and you **cannot** convert those equality tests to `LIKE`

Comment: @Used_By_Already Yes you can: `col like any(array[pat1, pat2, pat3])`. The real question is will the `:studentIdList` in `student_id like any(array[:studentIdList]))` be handled properly.

Comment: `any(array` is not the same as `in ( ...)` the question asked for the latter. You have substituted that for a different feature. My comment above remains true, about the use of in()

Comment: @Used_By_Already You misunderstand. `col in (a, b, c)` is equivalent to `col = any(array[a, b, c])` (and PostgreSQL even converts `in` to `any(array[])`) so `col like any(array[pat1, pat2, pat3])` is the LIKE form of `in (list)`.

Comment: @muistooshort [IN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-IN-SCALAR) <>  [ANY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16)  you have **substituted** the first for the second. Even the documentation on IN states *"This is a shorthand notation for expression = value1 OR expression = value2 OR ..."* try this: https://rextester.com/DUZZ23268

Comment: @Used_By_Already But your own example shows that `in (...)` is equivalent to `= any(array[...])` (or since no pattern matching is involved, `like any(array[...])`). `c in ('a', 'b', 'c')`, `c = 'a' or c = 'b' or c = 'c'`, `c = any(array['a', 'b', 'c'])`, and even `c like any(array['a', 'b', 'c'])` are all equivalent. You can always substitute `= any(array[list])` for `in (list)` because they're two ways of writing the same thing, try this: https://rextester.com/JOTP30415

Comment: "*How to use sql IN clause with sql LIKE*" No amount of  examples will assist. I was being "literal". The question asked for use of IN with LIKE. Substitution does not answer that very specific question. In fact by answering the question (as I did) it forces one to consider alternatives. May we end this now?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by individual LIKEs with ORs:

```
SELECT student_id FROM student_records
WHERE student_id LIKE '%input_student_id'
OR  student_id LIKE 'input_student_id%'
OR  student_id LIKE '%input_student_id%';
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318126/using-sql-like-and-in-together)