# Java PreparedStatement: any way to use indexed or named parameters?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm dealing with a situation where I use parameters in a `PreparedStatement` multiple times:

```
SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE
WHERE (A LIKE 'searchterm1' OR B LIKE 'searchterm1' OR C LIKE 'searchterm1')
AND   (A LIKE 'searchterm2' OR B LIKE 'searchterm2' OR C LIKE 'searchterm2')
```

When filling the parameters, I have to supply each parameter (searchterm1 and searchterm2) multiple times:

```
try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE " +
                " WHERE (A LIKE ? OR B LIKE ? OR C LIKE ?) " +
                " AND   (A LIKE ? OR B LIKE ? OR C LIKE ?")) {
    statement.setString(1, "searchterm1");
    statement.setString(2, "searchterm1");
    statement.setString(3, "searchterm1");
    statement.setString(4, "searchterm2");
    statement.setString(5, "searchterm2");
    statement.setString(6, "searchterm2");
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
}
```

Is there a way to **reference the same parameter multiple times in a prepared statement query**, so I only need to set it once (per parameter)?
So something like

- Named parameters: `:searchterm1`, or
- Indexed parameters: `?1`

Comment: The solution from the duplicate uses procedures, not sure if these are available to you

Comment: Maybe this helps you too: [Using SQL LIKE and IN together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2318163/5515060)

Comment: The Spring `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` in the reference question looks like a viable solution to me, thanks.