# Sql query with In and like operator or any other way around

Tags: sql

I was trying a query like this one, select * from table where column like in ('abc%','bcd%', '%cde') but not working. Basically I cannot use like operator with Or as I don't know how many values i will get at runtime. This values are coming from a subquery.

Requirements are to match with multiple values with pattern. But number of multiple values not known.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using SQL LIKE and IN together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318126/using-sql-like-and-in-together)

Comment: `values are coming from a subquery` - `from table inner join (subquery) on column like subquery.column`?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to use “union all”, seperate select query for each like statement, as below:

```
select * from table where column like 'abc%'
Union All
select * from table where column like 'bcd%'
Union All
select * from table where column like '%cde'
```